# System won't print this out?

Tags: java

// why wont this print out?? what other function could i use?

```
public class Exercise {

  private static int x = 12;
  private static int y = 28;
  private static double z = 3.3;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The answer to(x * y) / 3");
    calculate();
  }

  private static double calculate() {
    double you = (x * y) / z;
    return you;
    System.out.println("you");
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't compile because the `System.out.println("you");` is unreachable, as it is after a return statement. And your compiler would tell you this.

Comment: Im lost and a nube at this

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is more like this:

```
public class Exercise {

    private static int x = 12;
    private static int y = 28;
    private static double z = 3.3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result = calculate();
        System.out.println("The answer to (x * y) / z is " + result);
    }

    private static double calculate() {
        double you = (x * y) / z;
        System.out.println("you = " + you);
        return you;
    }
}
```

As others said, a `return` must be the last instruction of the method (unless enclosed in a conditional).
You have also to be careful: printing `"you"` is not the same as printing `you` the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
private static double calculate() {
    double you = (x * y) / z;
    return you;
    System.out.println("you");
}
```

The System.out.println statement is after the return statement. This is considered "unreachable" code and will not run. Put the print statement above the return statement.

Comment: "will not run" Yes, but more strongly, [it won't even *compile*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).

Answer (score 0):

1.this code wont compile.As,return should be the last statement in any function.the last statement after return became unreacable code because after return ,compiler stop looking for anymore statements.

2.in the println method "you" has been passed  instead of variable YOU.
println takes this "you" as string.
Correct code will be-

```
public class Exercise {

private static int x = 12;
private static int y = 28;
private static double z = 3.3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("The answer to(x * y) / 3");
calculate();

}

private static double calculate() {
double you = (x * y) / z;
System.out.println("you" +you);  // pass variable you instead of "you"
return you;


}
}
```

Output-

```
    The answer to(x * y) / 3
    you 101.81818181818183
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the method before your `System.out.` Another way to do this could be:

```
public class Exercise {

  private static int x = 12;
  private static int y = 28;
  private static double z = 3.3;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The answer to(x * y) / 3 = "+ calculate());
  }

  private static double calculate() {
    return (x * y) / z;
  }
}
```